# DNS Queries per zone

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

In the Google Developers Console I can see the estimated charges per project for the Cloud DNS service in the project overview section. When clicking the "Details" next to the estimated charges, I can see the number of DNS queries for that project in total.

Is it possible to see this number PER ZONE somewhere from the console? Like how many queries each zone individually gets. Or is this feature that would be introduced at some point in the future to the service?

Answer (score 0):

As Google design this charges inside Google Invoices, it's not possible at this time to split the cost of every single DNS zone. You have to calculate it using the information [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/pricing)

Comment: We wouldn't necessary want to split the cost per zone but just to see some information on how much each domain accounts for in the total amount. I don't think it's possible to calculate the DNS queries per zone as we don't get this information out anywhere from the Developers Console.